# How do I populate cell in CSV from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I am attempting to validate some URI's based on some domains in a CSV. 
This works so far thanks to The `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet in PowerShell. Any "200" response from the page and I know its valid. (I also found a nice function to make it easier)

However, where im getting stuck is simply updating the CSV file full of sites with the validated URL.

So my CSV is this for example

```
CompanyName,Domain
Google, Google.com
Microsoft, Microsoft.com
NotARealCompany, NotARealWebsite123.com
```

Currently my workaround is to just have a single column (strip the header and just the list the domains in a txt file) and my script now will validate the links that are returning a HTTP response of 200 and export it to a new txt file (see code).

```
Function Test-URI {
<#
.Synopsis
Test a URI or URL
.Description
This command will test the validity of a given URL or URI that begins with either http or https. The default behavior is to write a Boolean value to the pipeline. But you can also ask for more detail.

Be aware that a URI may return a value of True because the server responded correctly. For example this will appear that the URI is valid.

test-uri -uri http://files.snapfiles.com/localdl936/CrystalDiskInfo7_2_0.zip

But if you look at the test in detail:

ResponseUri   : http://files.snapfiles.com/localdl936/CrystalDiskInfo7_2_0.zip
ContentLength : 23070
ContentType   : text/html
LastModified  : 1/19/2015 11:34:44 AM
Status        : 200

You'll see that the content type is Text and most likely a 404 page. By comparison, this is the desired result from the correct URI:

PS C:\> test-uri -detail -uri http://files.snapfiles.com/localdl936/CrystalDiskInfo6_3_0.zip

ResponseUri   : http://files.snapfiles.com/localdl936/CrystalDiskInfo6_3_0.zip
ContentLength : 2863977
ContentType   : application/x-zip-compressed
LastModified  : 12/31/2014 1:48:34 PM
Status        : 200

.Example
PS C:\> test-uri https://www.petri.com
True
.Example
PS C:\> test-uri https://www.petri.com -detail

ResponseUri   : https://www.petri.com/
ContentLength : -1
ContentType   : text/html; charset=UTF-8
LastModified  : 1/19/2015 12:14:57 PM
Status        : 200
.Example
PS C:\> get-content D:\temp\uris.txt | test-uri -Detail | where { $_.status -ne 200 -OR $_.contentType -notmatch "application"}

ResponseUri   : http://files.snapfiles.com/localdl936/CrystalDiskInfo7_2_0.zip
ContentLength : 23070
ContentType   : text/html
LastModified  : 1/19/2015 11:34:44 AM
Status        : 200

ResponseURI   : http://download.bleepingcomputer.com/grinler/rkill
ContentLength : 
ContentType   : 
LastModified  : 
Status        : 404

Test a list of URIs and filter for those that are not OK or where the type is not an application.
.Notes
Last Updated: January 19, 2015
Version     : 1.0

Learn more about PowerShell:
http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/essential-powershell-resources/

  ****************************************************************
  * DO NOT USE IN A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT UNTIL YOU HAVE TESTED *
  * THOROUGHLY IN A LAB ENVIRONMENT. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.  IF   *
  * YOU DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHAT THIS SCRIPT DOES OR HOW IT WORKS, *
  * DO NOT USE IT OUTSIDE OF A SECURE, TEST SETTING.             *
  ****************************************************************

.Link
Invoke-WebRequest
#>

[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Default")]
Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory,HelpMessage="Enter the URI path starting with HTTP or HTTPS",
ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
[ValidatePattern( "^(http|https)://" )]
[Alias("url")]
[string]$URI,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="Detail")]
[Switch]$Detail,
[ValidateScript({$_ -ge 0})]
[int]$Timeout = 30
)

Begin {
    Write-Verbose -Message "Starting $($MyInvocation.Mycommand)" 
    Write-Verbose -message "Using parameter set $($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)" 
} #close begin block

Process {

    Write-Verbose -Message "Testing $uri"
    Try {
     #hash table of parameter values for Invoke-Webrequest
     $paramHash = @{
     UseBasicParsing = $True
     DisableKeepAlive = $True
     Uri = $uri
     Method = 'Head'
     ErrorAction = 'stop'
     TimeoutSec = $Timeout
    }

    $test = Invoke-WebRequest @paramHash

     if ($Detail) {
        $test.BaseResponse | 
        Select ResponseURI,ContentLength,ContentType,LastModified,
        @{Name="Status";Expression={$Test.StatusCode}}
     } #if $detail
     else {
       if ($test.statuscode -ne 200) {
            #it is unlikely this code will ever run but just in case
            Write-Verbose -Message "Failed to request $uri"
            write-Verbose -message ($test | out-string)
            $False
         }
         else {
            $True
         }
     } #else quiet

    }
    Catch {
      #there was an exception getting the URI
      write-verbose -message $_.exception
      if ($Detail) {
        #most likely the resource is 404
        $objProp = [ordered]@{
        ResponseURI = $uri
        ContentLength = $null
        ContentType = $null
        LastModified = $null
        Status = 404
        }
        #write a matching custom object to the pipeline
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $objProp

        } #if $detail
      else {
        $False
      }
    } #close Catch block
} #close Process block

End {
    Write-Verbose -Message "Ending $($MyInvocation.Mycommand)"
} #close end block

}
    $DomainList = Get-Content C:\temp\Sites.txt

    foreach ($Domain in $DomainList) {
        $Result = Test-URI -URI "http://$Domain" -Detail -Timeout 5

        if ($Result.Status -eq "200") {
            $Result.ResponseUri.OriginalString |
                Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\DomainExport.txt -Append
        } else {
            Write-Host "$Link did not respond....."
        }
    }
```

What I would like to happen, is for the CSV to be updated so that each domain is updated with the validated response URI (if its valid) or "Invalid" if it isn't, eg

```
CompanyName,Domain
Google, https://www.google.com
Microsoft, https://www.microsoft.com
NotARealCompany, InvalidDomain
```

This was my attempt, but i cant seem to get the Import-CSV piped to ForEach ...

```
    $DomainListOriginal = Import-Csv C:\temp\Sites.csv


    $DomainListOriginal | ForEach ($Domain.Domain in $DomainList) {

    $Result = Test-URI -URI "http://$Domain" -Detail -Timeout 5

    $DomainListAfter = @()

    If ($Result.Status -eq "200")

    {$DomainListAfter = $Result.ResponseUri.OriginalString}

    Else
    {Write-Host "$Link did not respond....."}

    }


    $DomainListAfter | Export-Csv C:\temp\DomainExport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You're looking for [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-3.0) and [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: Hi @AndersWiechers, Thanks for this! I know i need to use these cmdlets but i was struggling to use them correctly so i didn't provide an example. My bad, should have explained.

Comment: No, you should've *shown* your attempt at using them, even if that wasn't working. In fact, code posted here is expected to not work (otherwise you probably wouldn't be posting the question in the first place). As it stands your question does not show an attempt to solve the problem yourself, and instead is asking "please rewrite this piece of code according to my requirements". Which is frowned upon here.

Comment: You are right, so i will edit my code to show my original attempt. Bare in mind that sometimes people are a bit ashamed of our attempts but to hide it also doesn't help....So thanks for helping me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @AnsgarWiechers, it would look something like this:

```
$DomainList = Import-Csv C:\temp\Sites.csv

#Create Empty array to hold results
$Output = @()

foreach ($Domain in $DomainList) {
    $Link = "http://$($Domain.Domain)"
    $Result = Test-URI -URI $Link -Detail -Timeout 5

    #Pre-load Temporary output object with CSV structure
    $DomainOutput = $Domain

    if ($Result.Status -eq "200") {
        $DomainOutput.Domain = $Result.ResponseUri.OriginalString
    } else {
        $DomainOutput.Domain = "InvalidDomain"
        Write-Host "$Link did not respond....."
    }

    #Add to our Output Array
    $Output += $DomainOutput
}

$Output | Export-Csv C:\temp\DomainExport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: this is great! its got me much closer. Im just getting an error now 
Any ideas?


`Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At D:\Scripts\Get-SiteStatusTest.ps1:182 char:9
+         $Output += $Domain
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

I tried changing `$Output += $Domain` with `$Output = [Array]$Output + $Domain` which works for the very top row but not the rest

Comment: Also i added the function in the script block so its more complete. Not sure why i didn't do this before.

Comment: argh, the troubles of writing code too fast... *of course* Hashtables don't support `op_Addition`... only Arrays ;-) I should probably define one then! I have edited my post to fix the code.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I spend a bit of time on it last night myself but i was missing creating the Output array at the bottom. Makes sense when you see it.